# How to find out that if the index is in the nested list

Tags: python

```
from typing import List

def is_sink(m: List[List[int]], c: List[int]) -> bool:
    """
    Returns True if and only if c is a sink in m.

    Examples (note some spacing has been added for human readablity)
    >>> m = [[1,2,3],
             [2,3,3],
             [5,4,3]]
    >>> is_sink(m, [0,0])
    True
    >>> is_sink(m, [2,2])
    True
    >>> is_sink(m, [3,0])
    False
    >>> m = [[1,2,3],
             [2,1,3],
             [5,4,3]]
    >>> is_sink(m, [1,1])
    True
    """
    try:
        return if c in m
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

I am not sure about the try part but I did figure out the except part

Comment: Could you explain what it takes to be a sink ? It's quite unclear why `[0, 0]` returns `True`

Comment: Your current code is incorrect. use `return bool(m[c[0]][c[1]])`

Comment: @VineethSai `is_valid_index`

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to return using an `if` statement is wrong, here's how you can do it.

```
def is_sink(m: List[List[int]], c: List[int]) -> bool:
    try:
        val = m[c[0]][c[1]]
        return True
    except IndexError:
        return False


m = [[1,2,3],[2,3,3],[5,4,3]]
print(is_sink(m, [1,1]))
print(is_sink(m, [3,0]))
```

Outputs:

```
True
False
```

Comment: yes, thank you that's exactly how it was supposed to work, i think i miss understood the reference I thought the function checks if the number in the second list are the same, if they are not they are false

Comment: @BeierMu Accept the answer so it is marked as solved, Thanks.